When to use low and high speed on a combination machine
I have an old (mid-70s) cast iron combination machine with two speeds: 1500 and 3000 rpm at the motor shaft. I’ve not calculated the arbor speed, but for the purposes of this discussion, let’s call them low and high.
My experience in woodworking so far has been with hand tools only, and this machine is new to me.
It has several functions:

Table saw
Moulder
Jointer (with 3 blades)
Rabbeting
Thickness planer (with an accessory device)
Drill
Mortiser

I’m unsure when to use each speed settin. Does each specific function of the above need a specific speed (high/low)? Or are generally all functions operated at any speed, and the switch from low to high or viceversa is only done depending on the type of wood?

Welcome to WSE. Can you share the brand/model and motor size?

Thank you. It's a Spanish brand, which no longer exists: Sagrera. 3HP Dahlander motor.

Hi, welcome to Woodworking! "Does each specific function of the above need a specific speed (high/low)?" It depends on various factors. The main consideration is speed at the cutting face rather than RPM per se. Drilling is one of the classic use-cases for speed adjustment, since you can't run a large Forstner bit at high speed in hard wood, versus a 5mm twist bit which you'd obviously run quite fast as a rule in any species, although can be used slow to very slow if necessary (but not when drilling metal). For many other tools though speed is fixed, but feed rate is adjusted accordingly.

Thank you. "It depends on various factors" => these are precisely the ones I'd like to know about and better understand. The speed selection on my machine is essentially half speed or full speed, That is, it won't accommodate to the full range of factors. But having a rough idea of the main ones would already help me to know when to use the low or high setting.

Bear in mind asking what the various factors are for running stock through any given machine are in themselves valid Questions for here. So asking about 1 through 7 in a single Q is really asking too much IMO. This is why I didn't formally Answer — I couldn't face the 2+ hours it would take to write, cross-check/research, write some more to give details and insights, and then go through 2-3 rounds of proofreading, editing and proofreading again.
